# Batch Apex to auto-close opportunities if stage is Imported and 60 days after Action_BY_Date__c

Tags: apex, batch

I want to auto-close all the opportunities 60 days after Action_By_date__c and Stage is Imported. Opportunity must be closed by system where Stage = System Closed and Closed reason = Expired. When I try to push code it says Expression cannot be assigned due to "opp.Action_By_Date__c = 'opp.Action_By_Date__c + 60'". I am not sure how could I check for opportunities 60 days after Action_By_date__c.

```
public class CloseOpportunityBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
      return Database.getQueryLocator(
         'SELECT Id, StageName, Action_Date__c, Closed__c' +
         'FROM Opportunity' +
         'WHERE StageName =\'Imported\' '
    );
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> opportunity) {
    for( Opportunity opp : opportunity ) {
        if (opp.StageName == 'Imported' && opp.Action_Date__c = 'opp.Action_Date__c + 60' ) {
            opp.StageName = 'System Closed';
            opp.Closed__c = 'Expired';
        }
        update opp;
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
}
```

}

Comment: this could of course be done by Record-triggered flows w/ Scheduled Paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are abusing batch architecture by post filtering in your `execute` block. You should put all of your criteria in your `start` method wherever possible. Move your filtering to SOQL. Notice that you actually check for `StageName = 'Imported'` in the query, so post-filtering that in your execute block is already redundant.

Also, I highly recommend sticking to static queries *wherever possible*. Only use dynamic SOQL as a last resort.

```
public Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT Id FROM Opportunity
        WHERE StageName = 'Imported'
        AND Action_By_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:60
    ]);
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Opportunity> records)
{
    for (Opportunity record : records)
    {
        // no further filtering required
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Larson! Actually I am new to Batch Apex and learning as it is my first task but Really Appreciate your effort for correcting me and will try and implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
opp.Action_By_Date__c = 'opp.Action_By_Date__c + 60'
```

has two flaws.

1. It's written as an assignment statement (`=`) rather than a comparison (`==`). That's the immediate source of your error.
2. The right-hand side of the comparison is a string literal, not an expression. It sounds like what you want is to compare the stored date to *today's date* to determine if it is more than 60 days old.

What you need is probably something like

```
opp.Action_By_Date__c.addDays(60) < Date.today()
```

Comment: Thanks @David Reed! It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It kind of misses the big picture though.

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
Action_By_Date__c >= Action_By_Date__c .addDays(60);
```

Comment: if your batch deleting opportunity on daily basis